# sort function won't print sorted array?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

My sort function won't print the sorted array?

I'm trying to write a program that gathers array elements, sorts the array, then prints the factorial of each element. I don't want to get ahead of myself and write the recursive function if the array isn't being sorted correctly. The sort seems fine to me; people have criticized me using while loop but I don't know another way yet. Any input is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sorter(int numbList[]);
int getData(int numList[]);
//int recursive(int numList[]);

int main(void) {
    int x;
    int numberList[x];

    getData(&numberList[x]);
    sorter(&numberList[x]);

    //recursive(&numberList[x]);
    return 0;
}

//gets user input-data
int getData(int numbList[]) {
    int i;
    int x;
    printf("Enter number of Elements:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("Enter the values for each element starting from first 
element:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &numbList[i]);
    }

    printf("\nYou have filled the array list with\n");
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", numbList[i]);
    }
    return numbList[x];
}

//sorter function
int sorter(int numbList[]) {
    int x;
    int temp;
    int swapped;

    while (1) {
        swapped = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            if (i > numbList[i + 1]) {
                temp = numbList[x];
                numbList[x] = numbList[x + 1];
                numbList[x + 1] = numbList[x];
                swapped = 1;
            }
            if (swapped == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("Array as sorted:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            printf("%d\t", numbList[x]);
        }
        return(numbList[x]);
    }
}

//recursive factorial function
/* int recursive(int numbList[]) {
    int b = 0;
    numbList[b] *= numbList[b - 1];
    return 0;
} */
```

Comment: `if(i>x)` inside the `for` loop.... this condition will never be true

Comment: @AlexLop. thank you, just changed it to if(i>numbList[i+1]) but it still wont print sorted array

Comment: First of all please update the code here.  Secondly, what is the purpose of this check?

Comment: `x` is uninitialized when you use it to declare the array `numberList` in `main()`.  You've no idea what size your array is. The problems go downhill from there.  For example, `getData(&numberList[x]);` passes the address of the element after the end of the array — NBG. You need a function to print an array; you do not call it from within your sort code, but you can call it before and after you've sorted the data.  Note that 32-bit integers cannot store factorial 13; 64-bit integers cannot store factorial 21.  Decide whether to use `double` to hold larger value, or what.

Comment: I can see here too many issues (and I looked only at `sorter`) so maybe you just try to explain your algorithm? For example you are using `x` without setting any value to it, on the first loop iteration, if swap was not performed `break` is issued. in the `print` flow you always print `numbList[x]` and there are several more....

Comment: You'll need to determine the array size, `x`, in `main()` (or in a function called from `main()`) and pass that value to the other functions (as well as the start of the array). You also have `return numbList[x];` in the functions; that's accessing the array out of bounds – more undefined behaviour. The functions should either be `void` (return no value) or return a success/failure condition. Input can fail; your sorting shouldn't. Maybe the input should return a value (and check that the input succeeded by testing what `scanf()` returns) and the sort probably shouldn't return a value.

Comment: @Vpe Grill: Don't change the originally posted code. If you do, all comments & answers lose their meaning to other readers.

Comment: @Vpe Grill Also make sure you compile with all warnings on. The compiler will tell you a lot about things like uninitialized variables. Also consider your variable naming AND variable **scope**!

Comment: @GermanNerd ok, new to this site and second commenter told me to edit code lol , thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Vpe Grill Well, if you need to make big edits, either leave the old code as a comment in your code, or even post a complete new code. Best practice is to create a MCVE version of your code before you post it.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints as comments in your code:
It still won't do the job, but get you in better shape...

```
int main(void) 
{
  //uninitialized x!
  int x;
  //Even if you get a value for x, VLAs are depreciated
  int numberList[x];
  //Both calls get the adress of last value + 1 in numberList.
  //So you a) go out of the array bounds, and b) why would you want
  //the last element's address??
  //Just use it like getData(numberList);
  getData(&numberList[x]);
  sorter(&numberList[x]);
  return 0;
}

//gets user input-data
//What is the return value for?
int getData(int numbList[])
{
  int i;
  int x;
  printf("Enter number of Elements:\n");
  scanf("%d",&x);

  printf("Enter the values for each element starting from first element:\n");
  for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    scanf("%d",&numbList[i]);
  }

  printf("\nYou have filled the array list with\n");
  for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    printf("%d\n",numbList[i]);
  }
  //see above
  return numbList[x];
}

//sorter function
//Again, what and why return?
int sorter(int numbList[])
{
  //uninitialized x!
  int x;
  int temp;
  int swapped;

while(1)
{

 swapped=0;
 for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
 {
   //What do you compare here? Think.
   if(i>numbList[i+1])
   {
    temp=numbList[x];
    numbList[x]=numbList[x+1];
    //What do you have temp for??
    numbList[x+1]=numbList[x];
    swapped=1;
  }
  //Pretty sure you want an else clause here
  if(swapped==0)
  {
    break;
  }
}

  printf("Array as sorted:\n");
  for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
  {
     printf("%d\t",numbList[x]);
  }
  return(numbList[x]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the number of elements `x` is uninitialized when you define the array `numbList[x]`. This has undefined behavior. You should pass a pointer to the count to `getData` and this function should update this value, allocate the array, read the values and return a pointer to the array.
- You should not break strings on multiple lines without a `\`
- The swap code is broken: the test `if (i > numbList[i + 1])` is incorrect, it should be

  ```
  if (numbList[i] > numbList[i + 1])
  ```
- the swap code should use `i` instead of `x` as an index and the last assignment in the swap code should store `temp` into `numbList[i + 1]`.
- the inner loop should stop at `x - 1` to avoid reading past the end of the array.
- you should let the inner loop run to the end and break from the outer loop if `swapped == 0`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *getData(int *count);
void sorter(int numList[], int count);

int main(void) {
    int x;
    int *numberList;

    numberList = getData(&x);
    if (numberList != NULL) {
        printf("Elements entered:");
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            printf(" %d", numberList[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        sorter(numberList, x);
        printf("Sorted array:");
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            printf(" %d", numberList[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(numberList);
    }
    return 0;
}

//gets user input-data
int *getData(int *countp) {
    int i, x;
    int *numbList;

    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1 || x <= 0) {
        printf("Invalid size:");
        return NULL;
    }
    numbList = calloc(sizeof *numbList, x);
    if (numbList == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation error:");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("Enter the element values: ");
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &numbList[i]) != 1) {
            free(numbList);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    *countp = x;
    return numbList;
}

//sorter function

void sorter(int numbList[], int x) {
    for (;;) {
        int swapped = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x - 1; i++) {
            if (numbList[i] > numbList[i + 1]) {
                int temp = numbList[i];
                numbList[i] = numbList[i + 1];
                numbList[i + 1] = temp;
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
        if (swapped == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bubble sort algorithm technique which is fast sorting algorithm and it uses for loop instead of while loop

```
    int bubbleSorter(int numbList[])
{
    int temp;
    int i, x;

    bool swapped = false;
    for (i = 0; i < x - 1; i++)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (j = 0; j < x - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            if (list[j] > list[j + 1])
            {
                temp = list[j];
                list[j] = list[j + 1];
                list[j + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
            else {
                swapped = false;
            }

        }

        // if no number was swapped that means 
        //   array is sorted now, break the loop. 
        if (!swapped) {
            break;
        }

        printf("Array as sorted:\n");

        for (int i = 0; i<x; i++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", numbList[x]);
        }
        return(numbList[x]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Bubble sort is NOT fast.